# change value in udev rule to 45% ATTR{capacity}=="[0-5]"

Tags: udev

I have an old laptop which poweroff when battery is about 40% so I would like to add udev rule to suspend the laptop at 45% from arch wiki I found a udev rule to suspend when battery is 5% or lower
how to set the value to 45% ?

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="[0-5]", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl suspend"
```

Comment: No that did not work.

Comment: to make sure the rule is correct I am testing the rule in another laptop, which works just fine when the the value is  ATTR{capacity}=="[0-5]" and I am trying to edit the value to ATTR{capacity}=="45" and the battery now is 39% and the laptop did not suspend.

Comment: then try `ATTR{capacity}=="4[1-5]"` (play with the range... perhaps the udev discharge events are reported in steps of n percents so you may not get exactly 45 as value so it might need a range)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the right way to change the value to 45% is:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="[0-4][0-5]", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl suspend"
```

Comment: `[0-5][0-4]` is never `45`, just so you know...

Comment: well, I am surprised as well, but it just works in that way.

Comment: answer edited to the right value.